# Falied to register i2c-dev module

Tags: embedded-linux, i2c

I'm trying to run some i2c testcases for ltp-ddt on arm board.
I installed i2c-tools, i checked i2c devices in /dev folder, 
$ls  /dev/i2c-*
/dev/i2c-0  /dev/i2c-1  /dev/i2c-2  /dev/i2c-3.
But, when i try to detect i2c devices by running
$i2cdetect -a 0
its throwing error as,
 Error: Could not open file `/dev/i2c-0': No such device or address
Please let me know the valid solution ASAP.

Comment: Did you run '$i2cdetect -a 0' as root user, (equivalently, through sudo)? Or did you run it as ordinary user? It may help us if you add info on the output you get from 'ls -l /dev/i2c-*'.

Comment: Yes, i'd gone through all the possible ways includong the ways that u mentioned.

Comment: Are the bus lines properly pulled up or are they floating?